# How to decrease a value in a text box in VB6

Tags: vb6, textbox, type-conversion

I am a noob to VB and I need to know how its done.
Haven't done VB in 3 years cannot remember much of it.
The textbox has a value in it (5.43), and it needs to be decreased by 0.34.

But this is the code:
TextBox3.Text = Val(TextBox3.Text) -0.34

How do I do this?
**THIS IS VB 6** by the way

Comment: I'd love to know how you sample doesn't do what you want. It seems to work fine here...

Answer (score 1):

`TextBox3.Text = CDbl(TextBox3.Text) - 0.34`

Because your initial value has parenthesis (5.34) you must convert it to a specific number before operating on in.

Val does not recognize values in parens being negative. The `Val()` function in your original example is converting it to `0` in the same way that `val("abcd")` will also return 0 because it assumes both are strings.

You can test these conditions in the immediate window to quickly see the results.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried it, but could be:
TextBox3.Text = Cdbl(TextBox3.Text) -0.34

Comment: Ok, well I have tried that, but it then returns to being 0. Thanks anyway. Help?

Answer (score 0):

The following code will do it:

```
TextBox3.Text = Cstr(CDbl(TextBox3.Text) - 0.34)
```

But you should be aware what is going on.

The TextBox does not store a [double type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99xtshc.aspx), it stores a [string type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/thwcx436.aspx). The above code attempts to convert the string to a double, subtract your constant value from it, and convert it back to a string.

You should ask yourself what should happen if the string in the text box is not a valid number. In the above code, [Double.Parse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fd84bdyt.aspx) will throw an exception. [Double.TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/994c0zb1.aspx) will return whether the conversion was successful.

Or is it impossible to enter a non-number into the text box? In which case, the safety check is unnecessary, though advisable.

You need to ask these questions when doing [type conversions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language#Typed_versus_untyped_languages), or your program will behave unpredictably when a value is not convertible to the type you expected.

A safer way to decrement it would be:

```
Const DECREMENT_VALUE As Double = 0.34

Dim isDouble As Boolean
isDouble = IsNumeric(TextBox3.Text)
If isDouble Then
    Dim newValue As Double
newValue = CDbl(TextBox3.Text)
    newValue = newValue - DECREMENT_VALUE
    TextBox3.Text = CStr(newValue)
Else
    MsgBox "The Value was not a Double! Could not Decrement!"
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But still nope. This is VB 6 by the way

Comment: for VB6, use `CDbl()` to convert, and use `IsNumeric()` to determine whether the string is a number.

Comment: Im totaly noobed to Visual Basic 6, where CDbl() IsNumberic() go?

Comment: @JamerTheProgrammer I added code samples for VB6 to the post. I can't guarantee they work though. I don't exactly have a VB6 compiler handy, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It might just work

```
Dim TxtValue as Integer
TxtValue = TextBox3.Text
```

Since TxtValue is Integer, the decimal will be automatically dropped.

Comment: I am curious to know, in what way do you interpret the original question to mean that the OP wants to completely drop the post-decimal portion of the textbox value?

Answer (score -1):

Like this??

TextBox3.Text=Double.Parse(TextBox3.Text)-0.43

Answer (score -2):

This will work in C#

double number = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);

number = number - .34;

Comment: Tried in VB, stillnot liking it :(

Comment: I just saw you comment about being VB6.

Comment: Yeah, sorry. What should I do? He cannot upgrade. Thanks for the help.

Comment: so what error do you get with Val(TextBox1.Text)?  If I remember correctly Val should be enough.

Comment: A guy above me posted this....TextBox3.Text = Cstr(CDbl(TextBox3.Text) - 0.43)
.  That looks right too.

Comment: nope, doesn't work Im afraid. Thanks for helping. Any other suggesting.